# Prove that lim inf$_{n} na_{n} > 1 \Rightarrow \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ diverges

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that lim inf$_{n} na_{n} > 1 \Rightarrow \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ diverges

The solution proof goes like:

lim inf$_{n} na_{n} > 1 \Rightarrow$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n > N$, $na_{n} = a_{n}/(\frac{1}{n})> \frac{1}{2}$

At this point, my question is, where did the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from? Then the proof goes on to say that

$\Rightarrow a_{n} > \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$ and by comparison test, since the infinite sum of $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, then the infinite sum of $a_{k}$ also diverges.

This part makes perfect sense. But I really don't understand where the $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\liminf c_n = C$, then for any $B<C$, there exists an $N$ such that $c_n>B$ for all $n>N$. If this weren't the case, you could show that $\liminf c_n\leq B$ which would contradict $\liminf c_n = C > B$.

They just used this fact with $c_n = na_n$, $C=1$ and $B=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: So if $B = 1$ in this case, the proof would still work?

Comment: no, consider $c_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$. $\liminf c_n = 1$ but $c_n<1$ for all $n$.

Comment: so basically it's making use of the definition of an infimum

Comment: Yes, since $\liminf c_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}(\inf_{k\geq n}c_k)$